# pygame не устанавливается из-за того что pip 19.2.3 и проблема в том что pip никак не хочет обн

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, pygame

Hа macOS пытаюсь установить Pygame через `pip install pygame` выдает ошибку:

```
WARNING: You are using pip version 19.2.3, however version 20.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command
```

Я пробую эту команду и многие другие обращаясь через python3 но pip всё равно не обновляется! Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это не ошибка, это предупреждение. Если есть ошибка, из-за которой не устанавливается pygame, то она должна вывестись выше этого предупреждения.

Comment: Это не ошибка. Можно иметь пип хоть доисторической версии и всё будет устанавливаться.

Comment: error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin/python3.8 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; вот такая ошибка

Comment: Пиши pip3, а не pip

Comment: Судя по ошибке 'gcc', либо у вас не установлены нужные библиотеки (sys, setuptools, tokenize), либо они не прописаны в пути, которым пользуется  'gcc', Это переменная с именем $LIBPATH или что-то вроде этого.

Comment: `ERROR: Command errored out` - это стандартный вывод при любой ошибке. Скопируй весь вывод терминала и добавь в вопрос - где-то в нем компилятор ругается. Зависимости все установил? `brew install sdl2 sdl2_gfx sdl2_image sdl2_mixer sdl2_net sdl2_ttf && brew install Caskroom/cask/xquartz`, вот вроде все библиотеки.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ну никаких проблем с установкой тут нет просто питон говорит что доступна более новая версия, можешь и желательно обновить её при помощи

> 'pip install --upgrade pip'

Comment: % pip --version
pip 20.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7) обновился pip, пробую команду python3 pip install pygame выдает ошибку - can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: % pip install pygame
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 reached the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7. More details about Python 2 support in pip, can be found at https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/development/release-process/#python-2-support
Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages (1.9.6)

Comment: 1 error generated.
    ---
    For help with compilation see:
        https://www.pygame.org/wiki/MacCompile
    To contribute to pygame development see:
        https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
    ---
    error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------

Comment: и рекомендует pip обновить а он же обновлен уже! а через команду python3 тоже ошибку выдает! Очень странная проблемма

Comment: а пробовал установить без python3 просто pip install

Comment: Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 is no longer maintained. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
и судя по тому что написано тут... у тебя python а нужен python 2.7 его надо установить с сайта

Comment: установил python2.7 и pip обновил, всё равно выдает ошибку при загрузке pygame! очень странно, продолжаю долбить разные варианты

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно ввести `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`, я тоже устанавливал, всё работает